# Update desde Suma de campos de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Hace unos días estoy intentando alguna forma de realizar una consulta y actualización a un tabla mediante otra. Les datallo:

Tengo 3 tablas, la primera es `Usuarios` que contiene la llave primaria `iduser`, la segunda tabla es `movimientos` que tiene como llave primaria `idmov` y llave foránea `iduser`  en esta tabla hay 2 columnas más que es `descripcion` solo hay 3 tipos distintos (compra, venta y bono) y `cant` que son las cantidades de cada descripción y la tercera tabla es `coins` que tiene como llave primaria `idcoin` y llave foránea `iduser`. En esta tabla hay 1 columna más que es `cant` que es la cantidad total de las cantidades de la tabla `movimientos`. Espero haberme explicado bien aquí, ya que es algo redundante.

**NECESITO:** Hacer una suma de las cantidades de la tabla `movimientos` donde solo me sume las filas que tengan en su descripción *venta* y *bono*; y luego reste las filas que tengan en su descripción *compra*, y luego ese total se actualice en la tabla `coins` de cada usuario o simplemente el de un usuario en especifico.

En la siguiente consulta solo traigo la suma donde el usuario es '1' y su descripción es *'venta'*, pero no se como podria ponerle una condición en descripción, si en caso tambien es *'bono'*, me lo sume también.

```
select sum(cant) as Total from movimientos where iduser='1' and descripcion='venta'
```

Con respecto la otra sentencia SQL que es para actualizar los datos de una tabla, lo hice con la consulta que puse anteriormente, pero no me funciona.

```
select sum(cant) as Total from movimientos where iduser='1' and descripcion='Venta'
update coins 
set cant = Total
from movimientos m 
inner join usuarios us on m.iduser = us.id user;
```

Es mi primera publicación aquí, y lo estoy haciendo después de buscar por muchos lugares sin encontrar alguna solución similar. Perdón si es un poco confusa mi explicación pero si tienen alguna duda con gusto les responderé.

Comment: Quité la etiqueta mysql ya que el título decía que es SQL Server. También quité esto del título, pues no debe repetirse las etiquetas en el mismo. Para más información mira [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Empecemos por como hacer una pregunta en SQL. En vez de explicar tus tablas, lo mejor es mostrar la estructura como código junto con los datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios(
    iduser  int,
    nombre  varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO Usuarios
VALUES( 1, 'Luis C'),
       ( 2, 'Sebastian B');

CREATE TABLE movimientos(
    idmov   int,
    iduser  int,
    descripcion varchar(10) CHECK( descripcion IN ('compra', 'venta', 'bono')),
    cant    decimal(18, 2)
);
INSERT INTO movimientos
VALUES( 1, 1, 'compra', 5),
      ( 2, 1, 'venta', 7),
      ( 3, 1, 'bono', 2),
      ( 4, 2, 'compra', 5),
      ( 5, 2, 'venta', 10),
      ( 6, 2, 'venta', 15),
      ( 7, 2, 'venta', 7),
      ( 8, 2, 'bono', 2);

CREATE TABLE coins( 
    idcoin  int,
    iduser  int, 
    cant    decimal(18, 2)
);
INSERT INTO coins
VALUES( 1, 1, 0),
      ( 2, 2, 0);
```

Ahora, para obtener la suma de los movimientos y contemplar unos como positivos y otros como negativos, podemos poner una expresión dentro de la función de agregado.

```
SELECT iduser,
        SUM( CASE WHEN descripcion IN( 'venta', 'bono') THEN cant ELSE -cant END) AS cant
FROM movimientos
GROUP BY iduser;
```

Una vez teniendo este resultado, podemos ponerlo en una tabla derivada o una CTE para unirlo con la tabla `coins` y poder actualizarla. Dejo también comentado el código para actualizar solo un usuario en vez de todos.

```
--DECLARE @iduser int = 2;

WITH cteMovimientos AS(
    SELECT iduser,
            SUM( CASE WHEN descripcion IN( 'venta', 'bono') THEN cant ELSE -cant END) AS cant
    FROM movimientos
    --WHERE iduser = @iduser
    GROUP BY iduser
)
UPDATE c SET
    cant = m.cant
FROM coins c
JOIN cteMovimientos m ON c.iduser = m.iduser;
```

Sin embargo, por motivos de concurrencia y tener siempre datos actualizados, puede ser más eficiente usar una vista en vez de la tabla coins.

```
CREATE VIEW vcoins
AS
SELECT iduser,
        SUM( CASE WHEN descripcion IN( 'venta', 'bono') THEN cant ELSE -cant END) AS cant
FROM movimientos
GROUP BY iduser;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SOE.
Prueba cambiando el orden:

```
update coins set cant = 
  (select sum(cant) as Total from movimientos where iduser='1' and descripcion='Venta')
```

La JOIN no acabo de verla clara, pero si va junto a la SELECT, pues debes cambiar el orden:

```
update coins set cant = 
  (select sum(cant) as Total from movimientos 
  inner join usuarios us on m.iduser = us.id user;
  where iduser='1' and descripcion='Venta')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el cálculo sumando unas cantidades y restando otras puedes utilizar la función [if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) de MYSQl.

```
if(descripcion='compra', -cant, cant)
```

De esta forma puedes hacer el cálculo para todos los usuarios:

```
select iduser, sum(if(descripcion='compra', -cant, cant)) as Total
from movimientos
group by iduser;
```

Para hacer el update de los valores de la tabla coins puedes utilizar esta misma consulta encapsulada dentro de una join:

```
update coins
inner join (select m.iduser, sum(if(descripcion='compra', -m.cant, m.cant)) as total
            from movimientos m group by m.iduser) t on t.iduser=coins.iduser
set coins.cant=t.total;
```